# JqueryMobile - how do i run a function only on one html page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i am building a new app using jqm.
all javascript is placed in index.html, on another page (cat.html) i am using infinite scroll to display posts in category, when you scroll, after 15 posts it loads more 15 and more 15....
after the cat.html page is visited and the function executed the functions is keep running on all other pages (only after you visit the cat.html).

this is the code of execution:

how do i tell other pages not to use this code?

```
$('#SaloonaMobileCatPage').live('pageshow', function(event) 
{

$(window).bind('scrollstop', function(){

if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() >= ($(document).height() - 100)){

$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
var id = getUrlVars()["catid"];
sf = sf + 15;


$.ajax({
type: "GET",
cache: false,
url: "http://saloona.co.il/mobile/mobile_xml/read_cats_xml.php?cat_id=" + id +       "&start_from=" + sf,
dataType: "xml",
success: parseXmlCatsMore
});

}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `pageshow` event fires for the `cat` page you can bind the `scrollstop` event handler and when the `pagehide` event fires for the `cat` page you can unbind the `scrollstop` event handler:

```
$(document).delegate('#SaloonaMobileCatPage', 'pageshow', function(event) {

    $(window).bind('scrollstop.cat-page', function(){

        if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() >= ($(document).height() - 100)){

            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
            var id = getUrlVars()["catid"];
            sf = sf + 15;

            $.ajax({
                type     : "GET",
                cache    : false,
                url      : "http://saloona.co.il/mobile/mobile_xml/read_cats_xml.php?cat_id=" + id + "&start_from=" + sf,
                dataType : "xml",
                success  : parseXmlCatsMore
            });
        }
    });
}).delegate('#SaloonaMobileCatPage', 'pagehide', function () {
    $(window).unbind('scrollstop.cat-page');
});
```

Notice how I added a namespace to the event types so I can add/remove just the event handler(s) I want to remove.

Another approach would be to add an `if/then` statement to the `scrollstop` event handler that checks if the current page is the `cat` page:

```
$(document).delegate('#SaloonaMobileCatPage', 'pageshow', function(event) {

    $(window).bind('scrollstop.cat-page', function(){

        if ($.mobile.activePage[0].id == 'SaloonaMobileCatPage' && $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() >= ($(document).height() - 100)){

            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
            var id = getUrlVars()["catid"];
            sf = sf + 15;

            $.ajax({
                type     : "GET",
                cache    : false,
                url      : "http://saloona.co.il/mobile/mobile_xml/read_cats_xml.php?cat_id=" + id + "&start_from=" + sf,
                dataType : "xml",
                success  : parseXmlCatsMore
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Notice how I get the ID of the current page by using `$.mobile.activePage[0].id` and check it against the ID of the `cat` page so that the code within the `if/then` statement will only run if the user is on the `cat` page.

Comment: thank you Jasper, you helped a lot.
second approach did the trick